# bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22) with Logitech M720 Triathalon Multi-Device Wireless Mouse

Tags: bluetooth

My Logitech M720 Triathalon Multi-Device Wireless Mouse always produce bluetooth error with Ubuntu20.04.

```
❯ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-12-02 13:37:53 CST; 7min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1068 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18933)
     Memory: 2.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1068 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
```

more details:

```
❯ journalctl -b | grep bluetooth
Dec 02 13:37:53 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Dec 02 13:37:53 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: Starting SDP server
Dec 02 13:37:53 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: Bluetooth management interface 1.19 initialized
Dec 02 13:37:53 WXZ-Ubuntu20 NetworkManager[1077]: <info>  [1638423473.4415] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Dec 02 13:37:57 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:37:57 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:37:58 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:37:58 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:37:58 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:37:58 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:37:58 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:37:58 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:37:58 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:37:58 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:37:58 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:37:58 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:37:58 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:37:58 WXZ-Ubuntu20 whoopsie-upload-all[1865]: /var/crash/_usr_lib_bluetooth_bluetoothd.0.crash already marked for upload, skipping
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:38:30 WXZ-Ubuntu20 bluetoothd[1068]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Dec 02 13:39:04 WXZ-Ubuntu20 sudo[6506]:      wxz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/wxz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status bluetooth.service
```

hardware info:

```
❯ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network:0 DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: a8:6d:aa:b5:bd:c3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-41-generic firmware=46.4d093a30.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:a1334000-a1337fff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno2
       version: 10
       serial: 04:d9:f5:33:59:18
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-41-generic duplex=full firmware=0.5-4 ip=192.168.123.123 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:123 memory:a1300000-a131ffff
```

Comment: I find M720 still work, but it disconnect and reconnect as long as this error occured.

Comment: I have the same exact issue on Zorin OS 16.1 - which is Ubuntu 20.4

Comment: The problem for me usually happens when I log in, the M720 mouse works for few seconds, then gets disconnected and connected again.